# Read-only access to brush in Backgroundworker

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, invalidoperationexception, brush

I have a list of objects which among other properties contain a Brush (property name "Color").

In a Backgroundworker I want to write the contents of these objects to a file.
Everything works fine until I try to read the color of the brush property.

```
//this works fine
var brush = myObject.Color;

//this fails with InvalidOperationException
var c= ((SolidColorBrush)myObject.Color).Color;
```

It seems as if my code is somehow modifying the color but I don't see where/how.
Is there a way to read-only access the color of the brush?

Regards,

tabina

Comment: are there any more clues inside the exception class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do i sense that you're accessing UI objects on a thread that didn't create them. You cannot access UI objects from a BGW thread. That's the golden rule not to forget using BGW class

Comment: How could I solve this? I thought read-only access would be fine.

Comment: It appears access is access.   Pass the color not the UI object.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to modify the objects after they have been added to that list, you might try to [Freeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) them before they get accessed from a different thread.

Make sure that the Freeze call happens in the UI thread, where you created those objects. You might also check if freezing is possible at all by calling [CanFreeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.canfreeze.aspx) beforehand.